# Fixed Header, Fixed Footer, Full Height multiple scrollable column layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm struggling with an application layout. I'd like to implement it with HTML & CSS only, but desperation is approaching. I need:

- A fixed height, 100% width, static header
- A fixed height, 100% width, static footer
- A fixed width content area, centered & full remaining height

The content area needs:

- 2 columns, both are full height

The above is fairly simple, but might need to change to accommodate this next part.

Each column needs:

- Static Header
- Static Footer
- Scrollable content area in between the header and the footer

I've spent the day trying various approaches (even one based on--gasp--tables) with no real success.

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Fixed height, 100% width, static page header     |
|----|-------------------|--------------------|----|
     |Fixed Col 1 header | Fixed Col 2 header | 
     |-------------------|--------------------|  
     |  Scroll overflow  |  Scroll overflow   |  
     |  Fixed width      |  Fixed width       |  
     |  Full height      |  Full height       |  
     |                   |                    |  
     |                   |                    |  
     |-------------------|--------------------|  
     |Fixed Col 1 footer | Fixed Col 2 footer | 
     |                   |                    |  
|----|-------------------|--------------------|----|
| Fixed height, 100% width, static page footer     |     
|                                                  |            
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: can you show your code? In a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't have a working solution. However, this JSFiddle, based on tables, "partly" works in IE. Doesn't work in Firefox. I got close to reproduce the table version using `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;`

http://jsfiddle.net/vna48w5w/1/

Comment: sigh... do not use tables for layout. Unless its tabular data you want to show. I will try and fix this for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. (I do understand that "<tables> are for tables of data, not layout." In my case, with full awareness of the typical downsides of using tables for layout, I could live with them in this situation. I'd prefer to avoid using JS for layout, though.)

Comment: What version of IE do you have to support? If only IE 11, you should use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got a working version, tested in IE & Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/vna48w5w/3/

border-box was quite helpful.

```
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after looking at your fiddle and telling you table layouts are the devil. Here is my solution. Note: the scroll isn't working because you didn't provide content... so you may need to fool around with that.

So here is the markup

```
<header>
   header
</header>
<main>
 <div class="col1">
     <header>header</header>
     <div class="foo">
         some junk
     </div>
     <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="foo">
        more junk
    </div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
</main>
<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

and here is the styles

```
body{
    height:100%;
}
header, footer{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:pink;
}
main{
margin:0 auto;
height:100vh;
background-color:blue;
}
.col1, .col2 {
width:50%;
float:left;
}


.col1{
background-color:red;
height:100%;
}
.col2{
background-color:green;
height:100%;
}
.col1 header, .col1 footer {
     background-color:purple;
}
 .col2 header, .col2 footer {
 background-color:yellow;
 }
 .col1 footer{
 position:relative;
 }
 .foo{
 width:100%;
 height:82%;
 overflow:scroll;
 }
```

you will probably need to play with it a bit to make it look how you want. But in the the fiddle if you drop these in it makes the layout the same as that picture you provided.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Perhaps I wasn't clear about the part that has caused me so much pain.  
 
If you look at my [Original JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vna48w5w/1), you can see the part of the requirement that makes this difficult. I need the footer to be "static", stuck to the bottom of the viewport. I need (in your Fiddle, main) the "content" to be 100% viewport height, less the header and footer. I'm working on an updated Fiddle [v2 link](http://jsfiddle.net/vna48w5w/2) which is a similar version, tableless, but still not complete.